# Flutter - how change language in image_cropper component?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

The default language of tools in this component: https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper  is english. 
How I can change the language of tools in this component?

Comment: let me know if my answer worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Image Cropper**, if you look at the repo, has the following comment:

```
  /// * androidUiSettings: controls UI customization on Android. See [AndroidUiSettings].
  ///
  /// * iosUiSettings: controls UI customization on iOS. See [IOSUiSettings].
```

Over [**options.dart**](https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_image_cropper/blob/9011bd303e74f81113cf61f49c8ad32e54005462/lib/src/options.dart) you have:

```
  /// Title for the 'Done' button.
  /// Setting this will override the Default which is a localized string for "Done".
  final String doneButtonTitle;

  /// Title for the 'Cancel' button.
  /// Setting this will override the Default which is a localized string for "Cancel".
  final String cancelButtonTitle;
```

Like the comments said, change those for your localized strings and use any language you want.